# DA40 avgas leakage on filling

Tags: fuel, fuel-tanks, diamond-da40

New owner of a 2012 DA40 50 gal fuel capacity.(Also new to aviation!)  Recently was having the right wing filled from about 14 gal and lineman stopped within 4 gal when he noted a puddle on ground. not clear if came out of fuel vent.  Mechanic checked over and found normal function. later completely filled and no problem.
I have been unable to find any diagrams to show how the 3 tanks in the wing are connected or the mechanism for venting.  Hoping for answers and education. Thanks.

Comment: welcome to AV.SE. I'm sorry, I don't understand. what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason it dumps out the fuel vent, but I can tell you from my experience instructing in DA40s for several years that you can top-off the 40 gallon tanks without them dumping out the vents, but with the 50 gallon tanks they will dump out the vents if you fuel to the caps.
I always asked the fuelers to "leave it 2 or 3 inches below" the top/cap to avoid this.